# how to compare the jTextEntry with database value

Tags: java, jdbc, passwords

```
try     
                       {

                                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                                 Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:voter.db");
                                  ResultSet rs;
                                Statement s;
                                        s=c.createStatement();
                                 p="select voterId,password  from voter where name='userName'";
                                  rs=s.executeQuery(p);
                while(rs.next())
                 {
                     vi=rs.getString("voterId");
                     pw=rs.getString("password");


                 if(voterId.equalsIgnoreCase(vi)&&Password.equalsIgnoreCase(pw))
                             {
                                           voting v =new voting();
                                           v.setVisible(true);
                                             this.dispose();

                              }else
                             {
                               System.out.println("Invalid pasword");
                              }
                        }
```

This is my code of login form where i am trying to compare voteID and Password of jTextField with the voterID and password stored in database. using neatbeans but it is not allowing me to login instead i entered the correct username and password.

Comment: yes i am trying to compare value of string type from resultset.May be there is something wrong may be my way is wrong plz suggest me

Comment: If  `voterId` is your `JTextField` for user ID, you need `voterId.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(vi)`to compare.  Similarly with `Password`.

Comment: here my voterId is a string type of variable ie String voterId=jTextField3.getText(); and after that i want to compare it with vi, similarly ,username=jTextField2.getText() but when i am compairing and clicking on login button it doesnt responding me that mean nothing happens.

Comment: If you want others to analyze your code, please do them the courtesy of properly and consistently indenting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting database row for username entered in gui. You are not using username from gui at all- your query has hardcoded `'userName'`. So you are getting password for user named literally `userName`.

Side note: storing raw passwords in database as plain text is a terrible practice from security side. You should has password using unique salt and store hashed password. Password entered in GUI should be hashed using same algorithm and used in query. That way if somebody steals database he will not be able to learn user passwords. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet for more details.

Using Java framework like Spring security would solve many of those problems for you. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ for guide how to use Spring Security to create login form. That example uses InMemoryUserDetailsManager but repleacing it with JdbcUserDetailsManager would create solution that uses database.